# LINQ ASP.NET InsertOnSubmit - value of type cannot be converted

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq

I'am new in LINQ.

I am trying insert one row into SQL table via LINQ, but with error: Value of Type `'sendStatus.OnePerson`' cannot be converted to `'iloTest'`

I tried `SELECT` as well, and its working => `connection to db is OK`

This is my code:

Protected Structure `OnePerson`

```
   Property name As String
   Property password As String
```

End Structure

```
Protected Sub btnInsert_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnInsert.Click
    Using dbContext = New sampleDataContext
        Dim newPerson = New OnePerson
        newPerson.name = "myName"
        newPerson.password = "myPass"
        dbContext.iloTests.InsertOnSubmit(newPerson)
        dbContext.SubmitChanges()
        getData()
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: What is `iloTests`? Should it not be `dbContext.OnePerson.InsertOnSubmit`

Comment: iloTest is table which i join via Linq - type System.Data.Linq.Table

Comment: `'OnePerson' cannot be converted to 'iloTest'`. The answer is right there.  You're trying to insert a 'oneperson' type into a table of 'ilotest' types, what ever that is.

Comment: Thanks, you are right of course... 

I changed newPerson to :  

Dim newPerson = New iloTest

And code works.